# Good accuracy and val acc from keras model but fail to predict, even predict the training data

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to build a computer vision to classify image of temples which contains 16 classes and around 60-70 images per class (and very few that only have 40ish data).

Here is the plot for the spread of my data:

[image: Plot for amount of data in each class]

I am using the VGG19 architecture and I modify the last layer a bit.

```
def get_base_model():
    model = VGG19(input_shape=(224, 224, 3), weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
    model.layers.pop()
    model.layers.pop()
    model.layers.pop()
    model.outputs = [model.layers[-1].output]
    model.layers[-2].outbound_nodes= []
    x = Conv2D(256, kernel_size=(2,2),strides=2)(model.output)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)    
    x = Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(2,2),strides=1)(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Dropout(0.3)(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    x = Flatten()(x)
    x = Dense(len(class_names), activation='softmax')(x)
    model=Model(model.input,x)

    for layer in model.layers[:22]:
        layer.trainable = False

    return model
```

```
optimizer = SGD(lr=0.0001, momentum=0.9)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(
    train_data_gen,
    steps_per_epoch=int(np.ceil(train_data_gen.n/batch_size)),
    validation_data=val_data_gen,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_steps=int(np.ceil(val_data_gen.n/batch_size)),
    shuffle=True,
    callbacks=[callback]
)
```

And I use image augmentation that flows from directory

```
image_gen_train = ImageDataGenerator(
                    rescale=1./255,
                    #preprocessing_function=preprocess_input,
                    width_shift_range=0.02,
                    height_shift_range=0.02,
                    horizontal_flip=False,
                    fill_mode='nearest'
                    )

train_data_gen = image_gen_train.flow_from_directory(
                                                batch_size=batch_size,
                                                directory=train_dir,
                                                shuffle=True,
                                                target_size=(IMG_SHAPE,IMG_SHAPE),
                                                class_mode='categorical',
                                                )

image_gen_val = ImageDataGenerator(
                                    rescale=1./255
                                    #preprocessing_function=preprocess_input
                                    )

val_data_gen = image_gen_val.flow_from_directory(batch_size=batch_size,
                                                 directory=test_dir,
                                                 target_size=(IMG_SHAPE, IMG_SHAPE),
                                                 class_mode='categorical',
                                                 shuffle=False)
```

(Pardon my pretty awkward indentation)
See that I commented on the preprocessing_function argument, because I've tried both using and not using it.

Here's how I try to predict all the data from the train folder

```
folder = 'candi_borobudur'
imgs = [img_to_array(load_img(f'images/train/{folder}/{img}').resize((224, 224))) for img in os.listdir(f'images/train/{folder}')]
class_names = ['candi_borobudur', 'candi_brahu', 'candi_banyunibo', 'candi_cangkuang', 'candi_dieng', 'candi_sambisari', 'candi_kalasan', 'candi_pawon', 'candi_padas', 'candi_prambanan', 'candi_jago', 'candi_jabung', 'candi_muara_takus', 'candi_mendut', 'candi_sewu', 'candi_sari_']
print(len(imgs))
for img in imgs:
    #img = preprocess_input(img)
    img = img/255.
    img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
    result = model.predict(img)
    print(result)
    print(np.argmax(result[0]))
    print(class_names[np.argmax(result[0], axis=-1)])
```

The model got a pretty generous 90% validation accuracy after around 40 epochs, but the model fail to give accurate prediction even to predict the train data. Which when I run the code above, it predicts other class.

***Things that I have done:***

- Used preprocessing_input from the VGG19 class for both training and
  predicting.
- Tried to change the last activation function to sigmoid, relu, and tanh.
- Tried to change the optimizer to adam, nadam, and changing the learning rate.
- Changed the last layer into simpler layer (only dropout and fc)
- Cleaned the data, removing bad image, use simpler image.

***Things that I havent done:***

- Try to gather more data

Comment: First of all, try to train it with only one sample, and predict that particular sample. That can restrict the possible issues a lot

Answer (score 0):

By reading all your above try, I think your network is fine. 
There's a large chance that your **load_img** method is PIL based. 
This is different from OpenCV that each pixel value will be in the range of [0, 1]. You code require the image be in the range of [0, 255] and in float type.

Could you provide the detail of load_img and img_to_array in this line. Or print the array of image returned by **img_to_array(load_img** and **load_img**

```
imgs = [img_to_array(load_img(f'images/train/{folder}/{img}').resize((224, 224))) for img in os.listdir(f'images/train/{folder}')]
```